# Google Sheets APP script: Import CSV in a specific Delimited Character

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script to import my CSV file from my drive folder into my Google Sheets.

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Test.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Testoutputs');
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

My CSV is delimited either  by a `";"` or vertical bar `"|"`...

Is there simple solution to import my CSV based on that delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to replace the separator with a comma, but you need to consider if the comma already exists and if you need to replace them first and probably adopt US regional parameter. I tried an example on my own dsv file

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("myDSVFile.dsv").next();
  var csvString = file.getBlob().getDataAsString()
  csvString = csvString.replace(/,/g, ".")
  csvString = csvString.replace(/\|/g, ",")
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Testoutputs');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```